# Adjunct phrase in a sentence with compound verbs

Tags: prepositions

In a sentence with compound verbs, such as "Roll twice and use the better result for both roles.", does the phrase 'for both roles' apply to the whole sentence, or only to the second verb?

Would the example sentence above be considered ambiguous by native reader?

Comment: This depends on context; it can't be decided from grammar. But in this case, I think it's fairly clear that it applies only to the second verb. There are much better ways to phrase it (e.g., *for each*) if you want it to apply to both verbs.

Comment: @Ivan Ivanov There's no adjunct clause in your example; just two coordinated main clauses.

Comment: What does "Roll twice" mean in this sentence? Without context, I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Mark, it's a sentence from tabletop game rules. "The dice" is omitted.

Comment: It's not "ambiguous" - it's just appallingly clumsy to use the homonyms *roll/role* in the same utterance.

Comment: @Hardevgun This is the second warning. Do not edit the post just for punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the single higher result of the two rolls to apply to both roles, say

**Roll twice, *using* the better result for both roles.**

Even there, however, there is room for misunderstanding. So if it's critical that both roles receive the same value:

**Roll twice, and take the better result and apply it to each of the two roles so that they begin with the same value.**

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit bleary today, but I can't see any scope for ambiguity (in the written form, I mean; as a *spoken* utterance it's pretty stupid). Humour me, and spell out exactly what alternative interpretation might be credible.

Comment: For each of the two roles, roll twice, taking the better result.

Comment: oic. Well, we should leave those comments in case any one else doesn't see that possibility.

Comment: I'm not familiar with table games, but aren't you talking about two ***rolls*** [of the dice] and not two **roles**? I'm sure it's just me, but I'm not getting it. Sorry.

Comment: OP has both "roll" and "roles" so I assume both are involved. For example, in a role-playing game where the number of "lives" the roles are granted at the outset is determined by a roll of the dice.